# Please solve the problem of definition of Renpy

Tags: python, error-handling, renpy

I'm facing a problem about Renpy that it won't recognize original python definition like this

```
I'm sorry, but an uncaught exception occurred.

While running game code:
  File "game/script.rpy", line 44, in script
    python:
  File "game/script.rpy", line 47, in <module>
    response = generate_text(message)
NameError: name 'generate_text' is not defined

-- Full Traceback ------------------------------------------------------------

Full traceback:
  File "game/script.rpy", line 44, in script
    python:
  File "C:\Users\shion\OneDrive\desktop\renpy-8.1.3-sdk\renpy\ast.py", line 1138, in execute
    renpy.python.py_exec_bytecode(self.code.bytecode, self.hide, store=self.store)
  File "C:\Users\shion\OneDrive\desktop\renpy-8.1.3-sdk\renpy\python.py", line 1122, in py_exec_bytecode
    exec(bytecode, globals, locals)
  File "game/script.rpy", line 47, in <module>
    response = generate_text(message)
NameError: name 'generate_text' is not defined

Windows-10-10.0.22621 AMD64
Ren'Py 8.1.3.23091805
Live2D_AI 1.0
Wed Oct 25 00:44:38 2023
```

I tried several times to fix it but it won't work so I need help.

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
import sentencepiece

model_name = "C:/Users/shion/OneDrive/desktop/renpy-8.1.3-sdk/Live2D_AI/game/fine-tuned-model"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, padding_side="left")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)

def generate_text(message, length=50):
    input_ids = tokenizer.encode(message, return_tensors='pt', padding=True, truncation=True)
    attention_mask = input_ids.ne(tokenizer.pad_token_id).float()
    output = model.generate(
        input_ids=input_ids,
        max_length=length + len(input_ids[0]),
        attention_mask=attention_mask,
        pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
        do_sample=True,
        top_k=50,
        top_p=0.95,
        temperature=1.0,
        num_return_sequences=1,
    )

    response = tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
    return response
```

```
define e = Character("Hiyori")

define config.gl2 = True
image hiyori = Live2D("Resources/hiyori", base=.6, loop = True, fade=True)

label start:
    $ renpy.block_rollback()

    show hiyori m01

    jump talk_keyboard
    return

label talk_keyboard:
    $ renpy.block_rollback()
    show hiyori m02
    python:
        thinking = 0
        message = renpy.input("You：")
        response = generate_text(message)
    if message.lower() == 'quit':
        e "Goodbye!"
        return
        jump checkRes

label checkRes:
    $ renpy.block_rollback()
    if(thinking == 0):
        show hiyori m03

        python:
            thinking = 0
        e "[response]"
        # jump answer
        jump talk_keyboard

    else:
        $ renpy.block_rollback()
        e "......"
        $ thinking = 1
        jump checkRes
```

Comment: Supposedly you need to explicitly import `generate_text`; assuming your Python script was called `my_functions.py`, the way you apparently do this is via `python in my_functions import generate_text`. You supposedly have to run that before you can use `generate_text`. Does that help?

Comment: I understood thank you. By the way, if the python script name is manage, from manage import generate_text is right?

Comment: Sorry, the problem still remains even I put  from manage import generate_text at the begining of the code that won't work.

Comment: That's not what I meant. `renpy` seemingly has its own syntax, and so in the `renpy` script, you would need a line similar to `python in my_functions import generate_text` in order to be able to use the function `generate_text` from the file `my_functions`. But I am not specifically familiar with `renpy`, so you need to investigate exactly what the correct syntax is, and you should look up examples that use functions from external python files in order to see the syntax and usage.

Comment: Sorry, I will search about renpy document and after I get beneficial something, I will tell you later.